# symfony 4 - Redirect after form select

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a problem: I can't redirect after submitting a form with select element.

I have to select a duty (permanence), and once selected & submitted, I have to redirect to its page. Redirect does not happen, below is the controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="home")
 * @Route("/permanences/{id}", name="perm_show")
 */
public function home(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(SelectPermanenceType::class, $permanence = null);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $permanence = $form['nom']->getData();

    }
    var_dump($permanence );

    return $this->render('webclient/home.html.twig', [
    'SelectPermanence' => $form->createView()
]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/permanences", name="permanences")
 */
public function index(PermanenceRepository $repo)
{

    $permanences = $repo->findAll();

    return $this->render('webclient/permanences.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'WebclientController',
        'permanences' => $permanences
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/permanences/new", name="perm_new")
 * @Route("/permanences/{id}/edit", name="perm_edit")
 */
public function form(Permanence $permanence = null, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
{
    if(!$permanence){
        $permanence = new Permanence();
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(PermanenceType::class, $permanence);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        if(!$permanence->getId()){
           $permanence->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        }

        $manager->persist($permanence);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('perm_show', ['id' => $permanence->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('webclient/new_perm.html.twig', [
        'newPermanence' => $form->createView(),
        'editMode' => $permanence->getId() !== null
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/permanences/{id}", name="perm_show")
 */
public function show(Permanence $permanence)
{

    return $this->render('webclient/show.html.twig',[
        'permanence' => $permanence
    ]);
}
```

The page is correctly displayed, the dowpdown as well, but when I select and send, nothings happens.
Has anyone an idea ?

Comment: You forgot to add the snippet to redirect, like you do in function `form`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the order of presence of your routes. They would better have this order:

1. home
2. permanences
3. show
4. new & edit

As below:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="home")
 */
public function home(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(SelectPermanenceType::class, $permanence = null);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $permanence = $form['nom']->getData();

    }
    var_dump($permanence );

    return $this->render('webclient/home.html.twig', [
    'SelectPermanence' => $form->createView()
]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/permanences", name="permanences")
 */
public function index(PermanenceRepository $repo)
{

    $permanences = $repo->findAll();

    return $this->render('webclient/permanences.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'WebclientController',
        'permanences' => $permanences
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/permanences/{id}", name="perm_show")
 */
public function show(Permanence $permanence)
{

    return $this->render('webclient/show.html.twig',[
        'permanence' => $permanence
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/permanences/new", name="perm_new")
 * @Route("/permanences/{id}/edit", name="perm_edit")
 */
public function form(Permanence $permanence = null, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
{
    if(!$permanence){
        $permanence = new Permanence();
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(PermanenceType::class, $permanence);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        if(!$permanence->getId()){
           $permanence->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        }

        $manager->persist($permanence);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('perm_show', ['id' => $permanence->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('webclient/new_perm.html.twig', [
        'newPermanence' => $form->createView(),
        'editMode' => $permanence->getId() !== null
    ]);
}
```

Also I remove the duplicate route definition for `perm_show`, at each route should only be defined once.